# Python: Sys.argv doesnt take arguments correctly

Tags: python, windows, cmd, arguments, sys

When i do

`program -opt1 -opt2`

in cmd, **sys.argv** in **program.py** looks like this:

`["C:\\Programs\\program.py"]`

On a different pc, also running **Windows 10**, it looks like it should:

`["C:\\Programs\\program.py","-opt1","-opt2"]`

How can I get this thing to work?

Edit: Doing this in PowerShell works btw

Comment: What is the output of the command `python --version` on each of the machines? If it works in PowerShell, perhaps you should use PowerShell.

Comment: Doing exactly what in PowerShell works? Running `program -opt1 -opt2`? That would be unusual since both CMD and PowerShell should use the shell API similarly if ".PY" is in the `PATHEXT` environment variable.

Comment: Anyway, superficially the broken result looks like a misconfigured file association. Verify in the registry that the "Python.File" open command is set to a template that includes command line arguments (i.e. `%*`), such as `"C:\Windows\py.exe" "%1" %*`. Then in Explorer, right-click a .py file and use the open-with dialog to associate it with Python (i.e. tell it to always use the selected application) as the suer choice. If you have the launcher installed, it should be the Python icon with a rocket on it.

Comment: Check the "Python.File" ProgId in both "HKCU\Software\Classes" and "HKLM\Software\Classes". Don't edit the HKCR merged view. Also ensure that ".py" is set to "Python.File" in both hives. Of course, you still have to actually associate .py files in Explorer, as mentioned above, because the user choice overrides the class-based ".py" association.

Comment: OMG THANKS it worked! I changed the file type (And corrected the Regedit thing, because the path was wrong) Thanks :)